# For storage of sparse matrices which is better a vector or a vector for each row different

Tags: c++

I an using a data structure for storing sparse matrices as follow. Like if I am having a matrix as follows [image]

I am using a vector of pairs to store the data. So is it better to store these value in a single vector like this:-

[image]

or will it be better to store them like this:-

[image]

I am using a seperate vector to store data about starting and end indexes for each row.

Which of the two methods will use less memory?????

Comment: I don't understand how the single vector works. What if there are rows entirely of zeros?

Comment: then the allocation would start with values of row two. That would be handled in the value in the row vector

Comment: If your matrix is only 50% sparse like your example, I would not worry about it.  The performance of a 2d matrix is very good and all your alternatives are going to be much slower.

Comment: thats just an example I gave what if i have a matrix that is 10% or 20% sparse??? or just a tridiagonal one???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a vector allocates a single block of contiguous memory (unlike a list), a single vector would use less memory by consolidating the heap overhead.  I assume the client interface is the same regardless (overloading operator[], for example), so your question is just about memory efficency.

Comment: yeah I am just worried about memory usage as data structure for sparse matrices should use minimum memory. Would the difference be too much???

Comment: Depends on the row count, which translates directly to your vector count.  Another possible advantage to a single vector would be locality of reference - cacheline efficiency and all that.

Comment: but wouldnt it be quite efficient in inserting values in case of vector of vectors as in a single vector if I am to insert values in first row I'll have to shift all the values of rows with higher indexes

Comment: Well, that's a different question (from which one uses less memory).  Yes, you might want to take runtime characteristics into account - how often you'll be writing vs reading, whether the data is static and you can reserve() the vector(s), and so on.

Comment: okay thanks. one last doubt could you give me some idea about how much memory difference would be there on an avg for increase in size of one row or 10 rows. The fact is currently I am using the second method as storing data and retrieving from it feels quiet convenient to me so would it be better so switch to the a single vector type or I could use my present data structure only if memory difference isn't that great....??? Also I have heard its always better to use a data structure which helps in faster operations inspite of using more memory so i did prefer the second one